# VB.NET Use With keyword on existing object?

Tags: vb.net, linq-to-objects, with-statement

Is it somehow possible to use the 'With' keyword on an existing object?

I would like to do the following using LINQ to objects and can't seem to find a way:

```
From m as Product in Me _
  Select m With {.Match = m.Name.IndexOf(query)} _ 
  Where m.Name.IndexOf(query) > 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there is no way of doing this (`With` can only be used with a constructor). It would violate the functional principles on which linq is built, specifically that there will not be side-effects.

Best bet is to create a new Product in your select with the Match property set.

```
From m as Product in Me _
Where m.Name.IndexOf(query) > 0 _
Select New Product() With _
              { _
                  .Match = m.Name.IndexOf(query), _
                  ...apply the rest of m's properties _
              }
```

Comment: This does exactly what I need to achieve! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

In VB.Net there are two uses of the keyword `With`.

The first is object initialization.  It's a means of assigning properties or fields of an object in the same line as an initialization expression without the need of a specific constructor for every permutation of fields.

```
Dim x = New Product With {.Name = "Foo"}
```

This type of expression can only be used to create new objects.  It cannot be used to modify existing ones.

The second use is the `With` statement.  This allows you to put an object in context so to speak and call many . operations on it without qualification.

```
With x
    Console.WriteLine(.Name)
    .Match = 42
End With
```

Neither of these though will allow you to use an existing object as a template for creating a new object.

Answer (score 1):

No. The problem is that the `With` keyword (the object initialization keyword, not the statement) can only be used after creating a new object.

[The VB team thinks](http://blogs.msdn.com/lucian/archive/2010/03/05/req26-allow-with-as-a-modifier-on-expressions.aspx) that the side-effects of using `With` on an existing object would be too confusing.

About your problem: If `Match` is not yet a property of `Product`, the cleanest solution might be to encapsulate the required output in a new object:

```
From m as Product in Me _
  Select New With {.Match = m.Name.IndexOf(query), .Product = m} _ 
  Where m.Name.IndexOf(query) > 0
```

Comment: Did you read that post? It sounds to me like they strongly reject the idea.

Answer (score 0):

With an extension method on `System.Object` that accepts a lambda, you can simulate such a feature fairly closely. [There's an example in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/688418/what-fluent-interfaces-have-you-made-or-seen-in-c-that-were-very-valuable-what/690761#690761), but it's in C#. It's probably not too hard to translate to VB.NET.