# Is it possible to refactor this extension method?

Tags: .net, extension-methods

I have the following extension method:

```
public static void ThrowIfArgumentIsNull<T>(this T value, string argument) 
    where T : class
{
    if (value == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(argument);
    }
}
```

and this is an example of its usage....

```
// Note: I've poorly named the argument, on purpose, for this question.
public void Save(Category qwerty)
{
    qwerty.ThrowIfArgumentIsNull("qwerty");
    ....
}
```

works 100% fine.

But, I don't like how I have to provide the name of the variable, just to help my exception message.

I was wondering if it's possible to refactor the extension method, so it could be called like this...

```
qwerty.ThrowIfArgumentIsNull();
```

and it automatically figures out that the name of the variable is 'qwerty' and therefore uses that as the value for the ArgumentNullException.

Possible? I'm assuming reflection could do this?

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/869610/c-resolving-a-parameter-name-at-runtime/869629#869629

Comment: Check http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2009/12/09/quot-magic-quot-null-argument-testing.aspx - blogged :)

Comment: I think this is a very difficult solution to a very simple problem... If you're using Visual Studio, you can use code snippets to make this very easy ;)

Comment: @Jeroen: You seem to be assuming that the problem is one of typing - rather than being refactor-proof and keeping the amount of cruft in the code minimal.

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/669678/what-is-the-smoothest-most-appealing-syntax-youve-found-for-asserting-parameter/1010162#1010162

Answer (score 35, accepted):

No, you can't do this. It would be nice, but it's not possible without some sort of AOP getting involved. I'm sure PostSharp can do a nice job, hopefully using attributes, and in Code Contracts it would just be:

```cs
Contract.Requires(qwerty != null);
```

Ideally I'd like a PostSharp attribute which generates the Code Contracts call - and I'll play around with that at some point - but until then, the extension method you've got is the best approach I've found...

(If I ever try the PostSharp + Code Contracts approach, I'll certainly blog about it, btw... [Mono Cecil](https://www.mono-project.com/Cecil) might make it reasonably easy too.)

EDIT: To expand on Laurent's answer, you could potentially have:

```cs
new { qwerty }.CheckNotNull();
```

And if you had lots of non-nullable parameters, you could have:

```cs
new { qwerty, uiop, asdfg }.CheckNotNull();
```

This would have to use reflection to work out the properties. There are ways that you could avoid doing the reflection on every access, building a delegate for each property and generally making it whizzy. I may investigate this for a blog post... but it's somewhat icky, and I prefer the idea of being able to just attribute the parameters...

EDIT: Code implemented, and [blog post](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2009/12/09/quot-magic-quot-null-argument-testing/) duly made. Ick, but fun.

Comment: I read your blog post, and you honestly don't have to go through all of that hullabaloo. Just implement a `ThrowIfNull()` method without params and let the stack-trace toting developer walk up the stack a little to figure out what argument is null. Just a thought :)

Comment: @RCIX, when throwing ArgumentNullException you are required to say the parameter name. If the OP didn't care about the standard then this wouldn't be an issue. Please see the API Design Guidelines: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/en-us/cpgenref/html/cpconnetframeworkdesignguidelines.asp

Comment: @Jared: I looked at both the Raising and Handling Errors section and the ArgumentNullException class, and i didn't see any mention of that.

Answer (score 3):

In a word: no.

The extension method is passed a value.  It has no idea where the value comes from or what identifier the caller may have choosen to refer to it as.

Answer (score 2):

> See also [ArgumentNullException and
> refactoring](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/kevinpilchbisson/argumentnullexception-and-refactoring) for a complete
> solutions along the same lines as the
> answer.

What about:

```
public void Save(Category qwerty)
{   
   ThrowIfArgumentIsNull( () => qwerty );
   qwerty.ThrowIfArgumentIsNull("qwerty");    
   // ....
}
```

then define ThrowIfArgumentIsNull as

```
public static void ThrowIfArgumentIsNull(Expression<Func<object>> test)
{
   if (test.Compile()() == null)
   {
      // take the expression apart to find the name of the argument
   }
}
```

sorry I don't have the time to fill in the detail or provide the full code at present.

Comment: You don't need the `return` part in the lambda.

Answer (score 2):

I find it easiest to do this using a code snippet.

In your example, I can type `tna<tab>qwerty<enter>`.

Here is the snippet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<CodeSnippets  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">
    <CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0">
        <Header>
                <Title>Check for null arguments</Title>
                <Shortcut>tna</Shortcut>
                <Description>Code snippet for throw new ArgumentNullException</Description>
                <Author>SLaks</Author>
                <SnippetTypes>
                        <SnippetType>Expansion</SnippetType>
                        <SnippetType>SurroundsWith</SnippetType>
                </SnippetTypes>
        </Header>
        <Snippet>
                <Declarations>
                        <Literal>
                                <ID>Parameter</ID>
                                <ToolTip>Paremeter to check for null</ToolTip>
                                <Default>value</Default>
                        </Literal>
                </Declarations>
                <Code Language="csharp"><![CDATA[if ($Parameter$ == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("$Parameter$");
        $end$]]>
                </Code>
        </Snippet>
    </CodeSnippet>
</CodeSnippets>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend that you rather do the following:

```
public static void ThrowIfArgumentIsNull(this object value, string argument) 
{
    if (value == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(argument);
    }
}
```

Using generics in this case doesn't seem to add any value.  But as to your original question, I don't think that's possible.

Comment: Using generics allows the method to exclude value types. Note the `where T : class`

Answer (score 1):

I like [Enforce](https://github.com/pocheptsov/lokad-shared-libraries/blob/master/Source/Lokad.Shared/Enforce.cs) from the [Lokad Shared Libraries](https://github.com/pocheptsov/lokad-shared-libraries/).

Basic syntax:

```
Enforce.Arguments(() => controller, () => viewManager,() => workspace);
```

This will throw an exception with the parameter name and type if any of the arguments is null.

Answer (score 1):

As of .NET 6, you can use the [following](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.argumentnullexception.throwifnull):

`ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(argument);`

Answer (score 0):

"Is it possible to refactor this extension method?"

As others already said, there's not *much* you can do without using some AOP involved (like package **NullGuard.Fody**), **but** you *can* spice up your version a little bit to make it more flexible:

```cs
public static class Requires
{
    public static T NotNull<T>([NotNull] T? arg, string argName, string? customErrorText = null)
    {
        if (arg is null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(argName, customErrorText ?? Strings.ArgumentNull(argName));

        return arg;
    }

   // For all types
    public static T NotDefault<T>(T arg, string argName, string? customErrorText = null)
    {
        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(arg, default!))
            throw new ArgumentException(customErrorText ?? Strings.ArgumentHasTypeDefault(argName), argName);

        return arg;
    }

}

// Extensions
public static class GenericTypeParamCheckingExtensions
{
    [return: NotNull]
    public static T NotNull<T>([NotNull] this T? source, string argName, string? customErrorText = null) where T : class =>
        source ?? throw ExceptionsHelper.ArgumentNull(argName, customErrorText);

    // For all types
    public static T NotDefault<T>(this T source, string argName, string? customErrorText = null)
    {
        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(source, default))
            throw ExceptionsHelper.ArgumentDefault(argName, customErrorText);

        return source;
    }

}

// Usage
public class YourClass 
{
    private void YourMethod(string? nullableParam, int nonNullableParam)
    {
        // option 1 - just param checking
        nullableParam.NotNull(nameof(nullableParam));
        nonNullableParam.NotDefault(nameof(nonNullableParam));

        // option 2 - param checking and value retrieval if no exception occurred
        var stringValue = nullableParam           
           .NotNull(nameof(nullableParam));

        var intValue = nonNullableParam 
           .NotDefault(nameof(nonNullableParam), /* optional */ $"My custom error text");
    }
}
```

I am using many more Methods for various types, like Enumerables, Strings, etc.

You can find the Sourcecode of an older version here:
https://github.com/CleanCodeX/Common.Shared.Min

or simply use the Nuget package, which will be updated from time to time so you only have to update the package if you want to.
https://www.nuget.org/packages/CCX.Common.Shared.Min/