# Checking for Null in Constructor

Tags: c#, exception, null

I'm really trying to figure out the best practices for reusable code that is easily debugged. I have ran into a common practice among developers that I don't quite understand yet.

```
public MyConstructor(Object myObject)
{
    if (myObject == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("myObject is null.");
    _myObject = myObject;
}
```

It almost seems unnecessary to do this check. But I think it's because I don't completely understand what the benefits of doing this check are. It seems like a null reference exception would be thrown anyway? I am probably wrong, would really like to hear some thoughts on it.

Thank you.

Comment: What you are doing is not required, you could check to make sure before you referenced the object, that it wasn't null.  Of course validating what you will be using when your object is intialized is a very valid approach.

Comment: @Ramhound - this is a common approach when using DI frameworks such as StructureMap where you don't necessarily have direct control over what is passed in to the constructor.  If your class is useless without `myObject` and this is the only place to initialise it then it makes sense to throw exceptions as early as possible so you know about them.  In a long running web app you may not know about the issue until someone happens to call a method that requires the object.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

To the compiler, `null` is a legitimate constructor argument.

Your class might be able to handle a null value for `myObject`. But if it can't - if your class will break when `myObject` is null - then checking in the constructor allows you to [**fail fast**](http://www.martinfowler.com/ieeeSoftware/failFast.pdf).

Comment: Very well explained. I especially liked the term "fail fast". Thank you for the insights.

Answer (score 3):

Passing a `null` object is perfectly legal in many cases - for this class the implementor wants to ensure that you cannot create an instance of the class w/o passing a valid `Object` instance though, so there have to be no checks later on - it's a good practice to ensure this as early as possible, which would be in the constructor.

Answer (score 3):

Others have already correctly stated that the passing of a `null` parameter may or may not be valid depending upon the functionality of the consuming code.

Where a `null` parameter is undesirable it is possible, from C# 7.0, to use *throw expressions* which allow us to rewrite `null` checking code much more succinctly as the following example shows:

```
public MyConstructor(Object myObject)
{
    _myObject = myObject ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(myObject));
}
```

The above will set the value of `_myObject` to the parameter `myObject` *unless that parameter is `null`*, in which case an `ArgumentNullException` will be thrown.

Answer (score 2):

if you under 4.0 you can do the following:

```
 public ctor(IEnjection ninjaWeapon) 
 {
     Contract.Requires<ArgumentNullException>(ninjaWeapon != null);
     this.deadlyWeaponary.Add(ninjaWeapon);
 }
```

if you under an older version, reference the Microsoft.Contract to do the same thing.

Comment: But Code Contracts will do nothing if they are not rewritten in post compilation step.

Answer (score 1):

The compilier has no idea about the value of an object, so you have to check this at runtime to ensure it doesn't get called with a null value.

It also depends on your particular solution. You don't need to throw the exception, I would only throw it if you can not have that value be null, and if it is null, that is an exceptional case.

Answer (score 1):

I think that it is not possible to tell generally whether checking for null is necessary or not. It rather depends on whether you can live with null valued variables or not. Null is not per se a bad state. You might have situations where it is allowed for a variable to be null and other where it is not.

Ask yourself whether it makes sense to allow null values or not and design the constructor accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You could implement a simple `ThrowIfNull` extension method to reduce the code you write each time.  Jon Skeet covered this in his [blog](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2009/12/09/quot-magic-quot-null-argument-testing/) and the referenced SO article [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1873264/is-it-possible-to-refactor-this-extension-method).

Comment: The blog link is broken, but I guess this is the same article: http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2009/12/09/quot-magic-quot-null-argument-testing/comment-page-1/

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly check for null because the compiler doesn't know, but also because null can be a valid argument.

Answer (score 0):

The benefit is that the exception will be thrown at the time of object construction, so you can easily trace which part of code is the culprit. If your code requires non-null `myobject` value and you don't validate it in the constructor, the `NullReferenceException` will be thrown when you use `myObject_` and you will have to trace back manually to see who sent that null value in.