# Throw an exception if an object is null

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, null, operators

I've recently discovered that this:

```cs
if (Foo() != null)
    { mymethod(); }
```

can be rewritten as:

```cs
Foo?.mymethod()
```

Can the following be rewritten in a similar fashion?

```cs
if (Foo == null)
    { throw new Exception() }
```

Comment: The way you have it is correct. The [Null-conditional Operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986595.aspx) only returns `NULL`.

Comment: There's no shortcut to throw an exception but one of the things you _can_ do is shorten checks like `if (Foo == null || Foo.Bar == null || Foo.Bar.Oof == null) throw ...` to `if (Foo?.Bar?.Oof == null) throw ...`

Comment: If my memory serves me correctly, any call to throw new Exception() actually guarantees that the method will not be inlined. Therefore, in the official Microsoft manuals they recommended ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull. This approach is extended in dotnet8 with new checks for utofrange exceptions. See issue 
https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/69590

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why you would..

```
public Exception GetException(object instance)
{
    return (instance == null) ? new ArgumentNullException() : new ArgumentException();
}

public void Main()
{
    object something = null;
    throw GetException(something);
}
```

Comment: Do not use throw. Microsoft creates special helpers that do not reduce performance.

Answer (score 29):

Yes, as of C# 7 you can use Throw Expressions

```
var firstName = name ?? throw new ArgumentNullException("Mandatory parameter", nameof(name));
```

[Source](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/03/09/new-features-in-c-7-0/)

Comment: Nice, but your arguments are backwards in ArgumentException :)

Comment: That said, they'd be the right way round for ArgumentNullException.

Comment: Can't find something for condition, for example `if(blub > 0) { throw exception}`

Answer (score 28):

As of .NET 6, you can use the [`ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.argumentnullexception.throwifnull) static method:

```
void HelloWorld(string argumentOne)
{
    ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(argumentOne);
    Console.WriteLine($"Hello {argumentOne}");
}
```

Comment: This method introduced with .NET 6 Framework, not C# Lang 10. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.argumentnullexception.throwifnull?view=net-6.0 
For example, if your project `netcoreapp3.1` framework and using C# 10.0 you can not use this static method.

Answer (score 8):

There is no similar fashion syntax in C# 6.

However, if you want you can simplify null check by using an extension methods...

```
 public static void ThrowIfNull(this object obj)
    {
       if (obj == null)
            throw new Exception();
    }
```

usage

```
foo.ThrowIfNull();
```

Or improvement it to display null object name.

```
 public static void ThrowIfNull(this object obj, string objName)
 {
    if (obj == null)
         throw new Exception(string.Format("{0} is null.", objName));
 }

foo.ThrowIfNull("foo");
```

Comment: The method call can be changed to:
foo.ThrowIfNull(nameof(foo));

Makes it safe if the variable name is  changed :)

Answer (score 1):

[If null then null; if not then dot](https://app.pluralsight.com/player?course=csharp-best-practices-improving-basics&author=deborah-kurata&name=csharp-best-practices-improving-basics-m4&clip=5&mode=live)

Code using the null conditional can be easily understood by saying that statement to yourself when reading it. So for instance in your example, if foo is null, then it would return null.  If it were not null, then it would "dot" and then throw an exception which I don't believe is what you want.

If you're looking for a shorthand way to handle null checks, I would recommend [Jon Skeet's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1873264/is-it-possible-to-refactor-this-extension-method) and his related [blog post](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2009/12/09/quot-magic-quot-null-argument-testing) on the topic.

[Deborah Kurata](https://github.com/DeborahK/CSharpBP-Collections) referenced this saying in [this Pluralsight course](http://www.pluralsight.com/courses/csharp-best-practices-improving-basics) which I recommend also.

Comment: Do not link to pages that are protected. What is the code you are referring to?

Answer (score 0):

Using C#10 with `Nullable` directive enabled I often need to transform the values of type `T?` into `T`. For instance I have a property `string? ServerUrl` in class representing configuration section (it is nullable since it potentially can not be set by user) and I need to pass it as parameter to method taking non-nullable `string`. It is tedious in many of such cases to handle missing value of nullable type. One possible solution is to use [!(null-forgiving)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-forgiving) but in case of actual `null` value it will produce just `NullReferenceException`. As alternative, in case when you want to have more informative exception, you can define extension methods for verified conversion, one for value types and one for reference types, like the following:

```
public static class NullableExtensions
{
    public static T ThrowIfNull<T>(
        this T? input, [CallerArgumentExpression("input")] string? description = null)
        where T : struct =>
        input ?? ThrowMustNotBeNull<T>(description);

    public static T ThrowIfNull<T>(
        this T? input, [CallerArgumentExpression("input")] string? description = null)
        where T : class =>
        input ?? ThrowMustNotBeNull<T>(description);

    private static T ThrowMustNotBeNull<T>(string? description) =>
        throw new InvalidOperationException($"{description} must not be null");
}
```

These methods take optional argument `description` allowing to capture expressions passed as arguments, using [CallerArgumentExpression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-10.0/caller-argument-expression) attribute.

Examples of usage:

```
string? a = null;
a.ThrowIfNull(); // throws exception with message "a must not be null"

int? b = null;
int? c = 5;
(b + c).ThrowIfNull(); // throws exception with message "b + c must not be null"
```

[.NET Fiddle example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/GjtFaV)

I do not suggest to abuse this approach instead of proper handling of nullable values in strictly-typed manner. You can consider it as way of assertion (or suppressing warnings) that value is set or otherwise developer's error has happened. At the same time you also want to have additional information and you are not considered with runtime performance impact (operator ! in contrast does not have any runtime impact).

Comment: Really nice IMHO. Maybe add `[NotNull]` in front of `this T? input`, and `[DoesNotReturn]` to method `ThrowMustNotBeNull`.